Can I not use joins with in clause in SQL
Assume you're given two tables containing data about Facebook Pages and their respective likes (as in "Like a Facebook Page").
Write a query to return the IDs of the Facebook pages that have zero likes. The output should be sorted in ascending order based on the page IDs.
Pages table:
page_id page_name
--------------------------------
20001   SQL Solutions
20045   Brain Exercises
20701   Tips for Data Analysts

page_likes example input:
user_id page_id liked_date
-------------------------------------
  111   20001   04/08/2022 00:00:00
  121   20045   03/12/2022 00:00:00
  156   20001   07/25/2022 00:00:00

Query:
SELECT p.page_id 
FROM pages AS p 
LEFT JOIN page_likes AS l ON p.page_id = l.page_id
WHERE p.page_id NOT IN (l.page_id);

Why am I getting output as no data to display?

The WHERE clause negates the ON clause. I.e. no result at all.

Sample data is great, but a complete [mcve] also includes the expected result.

You turn your LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN by putting a WHERE clause, then filter out the result.  Of course there will always be no result.

SELECT P.PAGE_ID
FROM PAGES AS P
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
     SELECT 1 FROM page_likes AS PL WHERE PL.PAGE_ID=P.PAGE_ID
)
ORDER BY P.PAGE_ID ASC


Hint: remove the where clause and see what data you get back.
A left join returns data that exists in both tables. So obviously you will get no data in the result by looking at data that's not in the result set!
So what you might want is an outer join, this returns a dataset that contains all the joined data, but some columns will be null. You can then query the resaults that are null for the rows you want.

A LEFT JOIN returns data only found in the left side table too.

Who upvoted this?!?

@Meenakshi: You should add that info to your question, by adding expected output, Please do not comment on someones effort of answering you with a statement that should have been give in the question!

The reason you're not getting any data is because of the way your query is structured. You're trying to find pages with zero likes, but the combination of a left join and a "not in" clause isn't working as expected. Instead, try using a subquery to filter out the pages with likes, and you should get the desired result.
One of the subquery I thought:
SELECT p.page_id 
FROM pages AS p 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT page_id
    FROM page_likes
) AS l ON p.page_id = l.page_id
WHERE l.page_id IS NULL;


Why the DISTINCT?  Do you think your query will become more performant whe you add that ?

Why the sub-query ? Do you think ....

Yes, you are right, I just figured out that DISTINCT won't increase the performance and its redundant to use in above question while we just need to take care of NULL page ids.

You are getting nothing to display because you are asking for rows where your two tables join on the page_id (your join condition) but where the page_ID is not the same in both tables -- your where clause. They can't both be true!
The second answer will work for you, as would
SELECT P.PAGE_ID
FROM PAGES AS P
WHERE p.page_id not in
(
     SELECT pl.page_id FROM page_likes 
)
ORDER BY P.PAGE_ID ASC

You don't actually want to join pages and page_likes, becasue then you will get one row per page-like, so you would get two rows for page_id 20001
